# Как разобрать URL на части?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, строки

Нужно поделить строку на элементы согласно регулярному выражению. На вход подается строка вида

```
http://(возможная приставка www)название сайта.ру/дата в формате Y-m/|Слово из нескольких символов|дата в формате Y-m-d|-|слово из нескольких символов|-|случайное число из нескольких цифр|.|слово их нескольких букв|
```

Т.е к примеру ссылка вида

```
http://www.site.ru/2013-07/lunniy2013-7-11-rost-don-860686.zip
```

Чтобы после преобразования возможно было работать с массивом типа

```
$arr[0]=http://www.site.ru
$arr[1]=дата в формате Y-m
и т.д
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярное выражение, пока ничего толкового не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = "http://www.site.ru/2013-07/lunniy2013-7-11-rost-don-860686.zip";
echo $str;
preg_match('#http://(.*)\/(\d+-\d+)\/(.*)(\d+-\d+-\d+)-(.*)-\d(\d+)\.(.*)$#isU',$str,$matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ )

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = "http://www.site.ru/2013-07/lunniy2013-7-11-rost-don-860686.zip";

preg_match_all("/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?.*?)\/(\d{4}-\d{2})\/(\w*)(\d{4}-\d-\d\d)-(.*)-(\d*)\.(\w*)/",$url,$result,PREG_SET_ORDER);

array_shift($result[0]);
unset($result[0][1]);
$result = $result[0];

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => http://www.site.ru
    [2] => 2013-07
    [3] => lunniy
    [4] => 2013-7-11
    [5] => rost-don
    [6] => 860686
    [7] => zip
)
```

Comment: а я вот регулярные выражения пока не понимаю((. Недавно только их изучил, хотя принцип до конца не понятен.

Comment: Вот вам сервис для тренировки :) http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: спасибо, буду учиться)